# Using concatenating assignment operator for 2 variables same time

Tags: php, operators, string-concatenation

Can I use`.=` operator to append the same argument to 2 or more variables at the same time?

Like this (not working but example)

```
$a = "Hello";
$b = "Hi";

$a AND $b .= " World!";

// Now $a = "Hello World!" and $b = "Hi World!"
```

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$items = array('Hello', 'Hi');
foreach ($items as &$item) $item .= ' World!';
var_dump($items);
```

Or:

```
$a = "Hello";
$b = "Hi";
foreach (array('a', 'b') as $key) $$key .= ' World';
var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
```

Comment: glad to help you friend :)

Answer (score 1):

No way to do this with concatenation assignment operator.